# Auto adjusting height of div as per content

Tags: html, css

Height of wrapper profile intro or profile card should be auto adjusting as per content. [image: image of work]

```
[work link][1]  
[1]: https://codepen.io/TA0011/full/RwBoPbd
```

Comment: The image you've provided seems to include stuff I don't see in the snippet

Comment: Also try and provide a snippet that only includes the problematic code

Comment: https://codepen.io/TA0011/pen/mdjvvRZ see this link

Comment: can't add more than 30k codes here

Comment: @ZachJensz can you do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you set `.profile-card .profile-details` to a fixed height of `250px`.

You can archive what you want by simply add a media query:

```
@media (max-width:768px) {
   .profile-card .profile-details {
      height:auto
   }
}
```

Answer to your comment: text is overlapping because you also set a absolute `max-height` for the parent element: `.wrapper-profile-intro`

As a quick fix you can just add

```
.wrapper-profile-intro { 
  max-height:unset
}
```

to the media query from above.

Tip: try to get rid of all your absolute sizes. They cause much problems, especially if it comes to responsive.

Read into Flex or Grid. They booth have the ability to make divs same size etc. So you don't need to set heights or widths manually to a fixed size.

Example usage of Flex, hope this will help you:
https://jsfiddle.net/jhpL2n5w/

Comment: Try resizing below 268px , texts gets overlapped.

Comment: added fix for the problem

Answer (score 0):

The Best Optimized way is to use Bootstrap.
first include bootstrap in your web head tag.

```
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

then

**.container-fluid** will the trick for you.

You can take a look at [https://www.ntafzal.com/](https://www.ntafzal.com)

**.container-fluid** is used in the first section for 100% width.

Comment: i know bootstrap, but i prefer making from scratch