# body content goes of out of container

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a responsive layout and hence faced an issue. Issue is that body content exceeds the the layout on minimizing below 250px; however i know below 320px it doesn't matter if it loses responsivity still it looks unprofessional. i hope experts will help me in this regard.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjMWV.png

```js
function toggleMobileMenu(menu){
        menu.classList.toggle('open');
    }
function toggleSidebar(menu){
    menu.classList.toggle('open');
  }
```

```css
html{
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,*:after,*:before{
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
body{
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding-bottom:12rem;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif !important;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.body-content{
    padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
    width: 100%;
}
/*Main ends here*/
/*Global*/
h2{
    color:  #007bff;
    font-size: 20px;
}
li,a{
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.button{
    padding:  9px 25px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 136, 169, 1);
    border:  none;
    border-radius: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    color: #fff;
}

/*Global*/
header{
    padding:0 20px;
    background: #007991;  /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #78ffd6, #007991);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to left, #78ffd6, #007991); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:space-between;
    z-index: 1001;
    position: -moz-sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky; 
    top: 0;
}
.logo{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    justify-self: start;
    margin:  10px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
header nav {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-right: auto;
}
header nav ul{
    list-style: none;
}

header nav ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.active a{
    color: #fff;
}
header nav ul li:hover{
    transform:  scale(1.1);
    transition:  all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
header nav ul li a{
    color:  #f2f3f5;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight:400 !important;
}
header nav ul li a:hover{
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 400 !important;
}
.access{
    margin: 9px;
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    position:  relative;
    z-index: 100;
}
.access button{
    padding:  9px 25px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 136, 169, 1);
    border:  none;
    border-radius: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    color: #fff;
}
.access button:hover{
    background: rgba(0, 136, 169, 0.8);
    transform:  scale(1.1);
    transition:  all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
.access li{
    list-style: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.access li a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
.access li ul{
    background-color: rgba(0, 136, 169, 1);
    display: none;  /*submenu dissappears when set to none*/
    text-align: center;
    padding:  10px 25px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
.access li:hover ul{
    display : block;
}
.access-menu li a{
    color: #fff !important;
    font-weight: 400!important;
}
.access-menu.reveal{
    display: block;
}
.access li ul li{
    padding:  5px;
    color:  #fff;
    display: block;
    font-weight:500;
}
.access li ul li:hover{
    transform:  scale(1.1);
    transition:  all 0.3s ease 0s;
}


/*mobile-menu*/
#hamburger-icon{
    margin:  auto 0;
    display: none;
    cursor: grab;
    background: rgba(0, 136, 169, 1);
    border-radius:  5px;
    padding:  3px 10px; 
}

#hamburger-icon div{
    width: 25px;
    height:3px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin:  5px 0;
    transition:  all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
.open .bar1{
    -webkit-transform:  rotate(-45deg) translate(-6px, 5px);
    transform:  rotate(-45deg) translate(-6px, 5px);
}
.open .bar2{
    opacity: 0;
}
.open .bar3{
    -webkit-transform:  rotate(45deg) translate(-6px,-6px);
    transform:  rotate(45deg) translate(-6px,-6px);
}
.open .mobile-menu{
    display:  flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items:  center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    position: absolute;
}
.mobile-menu{
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top:  24px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100vh - 50px);
    overflow: hidden;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    background: #007991;  /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #78ffd6, #007991);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to left, #78ffd6, #007991); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
    color: #fff;
    z-index:100;
}
.mobile-menu li{
    padding : 10px;
    font-weight: 400 !important;
}
.mobile-menu li a{
    color:  #fff;
}

.mobile-menu li:hover{
    transform:  scale(1.1);
    transition:  all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
@media(max-width: 768px){
    
    header{
        height: 40px;
    }
    .logo{
        height: 25px;
        width: 25px;
        margin: 8px 10px;
    }
    header nav,header .access{
        display: none;
    }
    #hamburger-icon{
        display: block;
        padding: 2px 7px;
        margin-right: 5px;
    }
    #hamburger-icon div{
        width: 20px;
        height:3px;
    }
    .mobile-menu li{
        margin-right: 15px;
    }
  }
  media(min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1020px){
    .logo{
        margin: 10px;
    }
    nav ul li{
        padding-left: 10px;
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    nav ul li a{
        padding: 5px;
    }
 }
 @media(min-width: 250px) and (max-width: 281px){
    .logo{
        margin-left: -10px;
    }
    #hamburger-icon{
        margin-right: -10px;
    }
  }
  @media(min-width: 282px) and (max-width: 320px){
    .logo{
        margin-left: -10px;
    }
    #hamburger-icon{
        margin-right: -10px;
    }
}
/*Card*/
.card{
    min-width: 15rem;
    flex: 1;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: #fff;
    font-weight: 300 !important;
    position: relative;
}
.card .category{
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    left: 0;
    background: #FF7F50;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 300 !important;
    padding:  5px 9px;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.card .flag{
    top:0;
    right: -15px;
    position: absolute;
}
.card .flag button{
    position: absolute;
    top:  -10px;
    right: 0;
    background: 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.flag #report{
    display:none;
    float: left;
    padding:0;
    margin-top: 22px;
    margin-right: 22px;
    background: #fff;
    color: #007bff;
}
#report p{
 padding: 2px 5px;
  top:-10px;
  font-size:10px;
  line-height:0.1rem;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.card img{
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    pointer-events: none;       
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;

    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    display:block;z
    object-fit: fill;
    height: 180px;
    }   
    .card-panel{
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        margin-top: -10px;
    }
    .card-panel .icon{
        cursor: pointer;
        display: flex;
        /*flex-direction: row;*/
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    .card-panel .icon img{
      height: 60px;
      width: 60px;
      border: 5px solid #FFF;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background-color: #007bff;
      text-align: center;
      color: #fff;
      margin: -25px 10px 0 10px;
      pointer-events: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .card-panel .icon i{
        font-size: 15px;
        line-height: 30px;
        height: 40px;
        width: 40px;
        border: 5px solid #fff;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: #007bff;
        text-align: center;
        color: #fff;
        margin: -20px 5px 0 5px;
    }
    .card-panel .icon .tooltip,
    .card-panel .icon .tooltip1{
        text-align: center;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        background: #fff;
        color: #007bff;
        font-size: 10px;
        padding: 10px 10px;
        border-radius: 25px;
        box-shadow:  0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
        opacity: 0;
        pointer-events: none;
        z-index: 1;
        transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.68,-0.55,0.265,1.55);
    }
    .card-panel .icon .tooltip:before,
    .card-panel .icon .tooltip1:before{
        position: absolute;
        content:  "";
        height: 7px;
        width: 7px;
        background:#fff;
        bottom: -3px;
        left: 50%;
        transform:  translate(-50%) rotate(45deg);
        transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.68,-0.55,0.265,1.55);
    }
    .card-panel .icon:hover .tooltip,
    .card-panel .icon:focus .tooltip{
        position: absolute;
        top: -60px;
        opacity: 1;
        pointer-events: auto;
    }
    .card-panel .icon:hover .tooltip1,
    .card-panel .icon:focus .tooltip1{
        top: -92px;
        opacity: 1;
        pointer-events: auto;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .card-panel .icon:hover i,
    .card-panel .icon:active i,
    .card-panel .icon:hover .tooltip,
    .card-panel .icon:focus .tooltip,
    .card-panel .icon .tooltip1:before{
        text-shadow:  0px -1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    }
    .card-panel .tooltip1 i{
        font-size: 8px;
        line-height:13px;
        height: 20px;
        width: 20px;
        border: 3px solid #fff;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: #007bff;
        text-align: center;
        color: #fff;
        margin: -20px 5px 0 5px;
    }
    
    .card .text {
        padding: 10px 10px;
    }
    .card .text h3{
        margin-top: 0;
        text-align: justify;
        text-justify: inter-word;
        font-weight: 500 !important;
    }
    .card button{
        background-color: #007bff;
        border-radius: 10px;
        color:#fff;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: block;
    }
    .card button:hover{
        opacity:  0.8;
    }
.card .see-more{
    top: 40%;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
.card .see-more i{
    font-size: 60px;
    color:#007bff;
}
.container-a,
.container-b{
  margin:10px auto;
  padding:0;
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
  position:relative;
}
.wrapper{
  height:100%;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas: "blog-container blog-container blog-container blog-container blog-sidebar";
  grid-gap:10px;
}
.wrapper .blog-container{
  grid-area: blog-container;
}
.wrapper .blog-sidebar{
  grid-area: blog-sidebar;
}
.wrapper .blog-container span,
.wrapper .blog-sidebar span{
    background-color: #007bff;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    position:relative;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: -1;
    background-blend-mode: multiply;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif !important;
}
.blog-container hr,
.blog-sidebar hr{
    width: 100%;
    color:#007bff;
    margin-top: 3.5px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -2;
}
.blog-container .blog-cards{
  display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(270px,1fr));
    grid-gap: 10px; 
}
.widgets{
    background: #fff;
    border:  1px solid #ccc;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(270px,1fr));
    grid-gap: 10px;
    padding:  5px;
}
.widgets img{
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
  display:block;
  object-fit: fill;
}
.container-a .widgets,.container-b .widgets{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.load-more{
    text-align: center;
    grid-column: 1/-1;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.load-more button{
    padding:  9px 150px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 136, 169, 1);
    border:  none;
    border-radius: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 13px;
}
    .load-more button:hover{
    background: rgba(0, 136, 169, 0.8);
    transform:  scale(1.1);
    transition:  all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

/*--MEDIA QUERIES--*/

@media(max-width: 768px){
    .carousel{
        width: calc(100% - 60px);
        margin: 10px auto;
    }
    .carousel span,
    .wrapper .blog-container span,
    .wrapper .blog-sidebar span{
        font-size: 12px;
    }
    .carousel hr{
        margin-top: 3px;
    }
    .horizontal-scroll .btn-scroll{
        padding: 0 5px;
        font-size: 30px;    
    }
    .horizontal-scroll #btn-scroll-left{
        top: calc(430px/2);
    }
    .horizontal-scroll #btn-scroll-right{
        top: calc(430px/2);
    }
    .container-a,
    .container-b{
        width: 99%;
        padding:  5px;
    }
    
    .wrapper{
        grid-template-rows: auto;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
        grid-template-areas: "blog-container"
        "blog-sidebar";
    }
    .card{
        min-width: 14.8rem;
    }
    
    .card .category{
        font-size: 8px;
        padding: 4px 7px;
        top:  -8px;
    }
    .card img{
        height: 150px;
    }
    .card .flag{
        right: -7px;0
    }
    .card .flag button{
        font-size: 15px;
        top:  -5px;
    }
    .flag #report{
        margin-top: 17px;
        margin-right: 12px;
    }
    #report p{
        padding: 1px 4px; 
        font-size:9px;  
    }
    .card-panel .icon i{
        font-size: 10px;
        line-height: 22px;
        height: 30px;
        width: 30px;
        margin: -12px 4px 0 4px;
        border: 4px solid #FFF;
    }
    .card-panel .icon img{
        width:  50px;
        height: 50px;
        border: 4px solid #FFF;
        margin: -20px 10px 0 10px;
    }
    .card-panel .icon .tooltip,
    .card-panel .icon .tooltip1{
        padding: 8px 8px;
        font-size: 8px;
    }
    .card-panel .icon .tooltip:before,
    .card-panel .icon .tooltip1:before{
        width: 5px;
        height: 5px;
        bottom: -2px;
    }
    .card-panel .icon:hover .tooltip{
        top: -45px;
    }
    .card-panel .icon:hover .tooltip1{
        top: -75px;
    }
    .card-panel .tooltip1 i{
        font-size: 8px;
        line-height:14px;
        height: 18px;
        width: 18px;
        border: 2px solid #fff;
    }
    .card .text h3{
        font-size: 15px;
    }
    .card button{
        padding: 5px 10px;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
    .widgets{
        grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(244px,1fr));
    }
    .card .see-more{
        top: 40%;
    }
    .card .see-more i{
        font-size: 50px;
    }
    .load-more button{
        padding: 5px 30px;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
}

@media(max-width: 281px) {
  .wrapper .blog-container {
    padding-right: 0;
  }
  .blog-container .blog-cards {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100%, 1fr));
  }
  .widgets {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100%, 1fr));
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="body-content">
    <header>
        <img src="img/Logo.jpg" class="logo" alt="Logo">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li class="active"><a href="index"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-pen-nib"></i> Blogs</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="far fa-images"></i> product</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <ul class="access">
            <li><a href="#"><button class="accessBtn"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i> Access <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></button></a>
                <ul class ="access-menu">
                    <li id="signup"><a href="signup">Signup</a></li>
                    <li id="signin"><a href="signin">Signin</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div id="hamburger-icon" onclick="toggleMobileMenu(this)">
            <div class="bar1"></div>
            <div class="bar2"></div>
            <div class="bar3"></div>
            <ul class="mobile-menu">
                <li class="active"><a href="index"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-pen-nib"></i> contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="far fa-images"></i> Product</a></li>
                <li><a href="signup">Signup</a></li>
                <li><a href="signin">Signin</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
<section class="container-a" aria-label="blog-content">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="blog-container">
      <span>Blogs</span><hr>
      <div class="blog-cards">
        
       <div class="card">
                    <img src="images/1.jpg">
                        <p class="category">Fashion</p>
                        <div class="flag">
                            <button onclick=myFunction()>&#8942</button>
                            <div id="report">
                                <p>Report</p>
                                <p>Not-interested</p>
                            </div>
                        </div><!--flag-->
                        <div class="card-panel">
                            <div class="icon">
                                <div class="tooltip">14.1k</div>
                                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                                </div>
                            <div class="icon">
                                <div class="tooltip">14.1k</div>
                                    <i class="fas fa-comment"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="icon">
                                <div class="tooltip1"><i class="fas fa-crown"></i>Umananda goswami
                                </div>
                                <img src="images/4.jpeg">
                            </div>
                            <div class="icon">
                                <div class="tooltip">14.1k</div>
                                <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i>
                                </div>
                            <div class="icon">
                                <div class="tooltip">14.1k</div>
                                    <i class="fas fa-share"></i>
                                </div>
                        </div><!--card-panel-->
                        <div class="text">
                            <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</h3>
                            <button>Read it</button>
                        </div>
                </div><!--card-->
                
        <div class="card">
                    <img src="images/1.jpg">
                        <p class="category">Fashion</p>
                        <div class="flag">
                            <button onclick=myFunction()>&#8942</button>
                            <div id="report">
                                <p>Report</p>
                                <p>Not-interested</p>
                            </div>
                        </div><!--flag-->
                        <div class="card-panel">
                            <div class="icon">
                                <div class="tooltip">14.1k</div>
                                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                                </div>
                            <div class="icon">
                                <div class="tooltip">14.1k</div>
                                    <i class="fas fa-comment"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="icon">
                                <div class="tooltip1"><i class="fas fa-crown"></i>Umananda goswami
                                </div>
                                <img src="images/4.jpeg">
                            </div>
                            <div class="icon">
                                <div class="tooltip">14.1k</div>
                                <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i>
                                </div>
                            <div class="icon">
                                <div class="tooltip">14.1k</div>
                                    <i class="fas fa-share"></i>
                                </div>
                        </div><!--card-panel-->
                        <div class="text">
                            <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</h3>
                            <button>Read it</button>
                        </div>
                </div><!--card-->
        <div class="card">
                    <img src="images/1.jpg">
                        <p class="category">Fashion</p>
                        <div class="flag">
                            <button onclick=myFunction()>&#8942</button>
                            <div id="report">
                                <p>Report</p>
                                <p>Not-interested</p>
                            </div>
                        </div><!--flag-->
                        <div class="card-panel">
                            <div class="icon">
                                <div class="tooltip">14.1k</div>
                                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                                </div>
                            <div class="icon">
                                <div class="tooltip">14.1k</div>
                                    <i class="fas fa-comment"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="icon">
                                <div class="tooltip1"><i class="fas fa-crown"></i>Umananda goswami
                                </div>
                                <img src="images/4.jpeg">
                            </div>
                            <div class="icon">
                                <div class="tooltip">14.1k</div>
                                <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i>
                                </div>
                            <div class="icon">
                                <div class="tooltip">14.1k</div>
                                    <i class="fas fa-share"></i>
                                </div>
                        </div><!--card-panel-->
                        <div class="text">
                            <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</h3>
                            <button>Read it</button>
                        </div>
                </div><!--card-->
        <div class="card">
                    <img src="images/1.jpg">
                        <p class="category">Fashion</p>
                        <div class="flag">
                            <button onclick=myFunction()>&#8942</button>
                            <div id="report">
                                <p>Report</p>
                                <p>Not-interested</p>
                            </div>
                        </div><!--flag-->
                        <div class="card-panel">
                            <div class="icon">
                                <div class="tooltip">14.1k</div>
                                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                                </div>
                            <div class="icon">
                                <div class="tooltip">14.1k</div>
                                    <i class="fas fa-comment"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="icon">
                                <div class="tooltip1"><i class="fas fa-crown"></i>Umananda goswami
                                </div>
                                <img src="images/4.jpeg">
                            </div>
                            <div class="icon">
                                <div class="tooltip">14.1k</div>
                                <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i>
                                </div>
                            <div class="icon">
                                <div class="tooltip">14.1k</div>
                                    <i class="fas fa-share"></i>
                                </div>
                        </div><!--card-panel-->
                        <div class="text">
                            <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</h3>
                            <button>Read it</button>
                        </div>
                </div><!--card-->
        <div class="card">Card5</div>
        <div class="load-more">
            <button>Load More</button>
        </div>
      </div><!--cards-->
    </div> 
    <div class="blog-sidebar">
      <span>Sidebar</span><hr>
      <div class="widgets">
        <img src="images/5.jpg">
                <img src="images/4.jpeg">
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is, that you set the `.card` class a `min-width: 14.8rem`, so it would be bigger than the actual body with at a certian point. You can resolve this by remove the absolute min-width.

Working code:

```js
function toggleMobileMenu(menu) {
  menu.classList.toggle('open');
}

function toggleSidebar(menu) {
  menu.classList.toggle('open');
}
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:after,
*:before {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 12rem;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif !important;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.body-content {
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
  width: 100%;
}


/*Main ends here*/


/*Global*/

h2 {
  color: #007bff;
  font-size: 20px;
}

li,
a {
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.button {
  padding: 9px 25px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 136, 169, 1);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  color: #fff;
}


/*Global*/

header {
  padding: 0 20px;
  background: #007991;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #78ffd6, #007991);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #78ffd6, #007991);
  /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  z-index: 1001;
  position: -moz-sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.logo {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  justify-self: start;
  margin: 10px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

header nav {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-right: auto;
}

header nav ul {
  list-style: none;
}

header nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.active a {
  color: #fff;
}

header nav ul li:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

header nav ul li a {
  color: #f2f3f5;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 400 !important;
}

header nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 400 !important;
}

.access {
  margin: 9px;
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}

.access button {
  padding: 9px 25px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 136, 169, 1);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  color: #fff;
}

.access button:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 136, 169, 0.8);
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.access li {
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.access li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.access li ul {
  background-color: rgba(0, 136, 169, 1);
  display: none;
  /*submenu dissappears when set to none*/
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

.access li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

.access-menu li a {
  color: #fff !important;
  font-weight: 400!important;
}

.access-menu.reveal {
  display: block;
}

.access li ul li {
  padding: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.access li ul li:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}


/*mobile-menu*/

#hamburger-icon {
  margin: auto 0;
  display: none;
  cursor: grab;
  background: rgba(0, 136, 169, 1);
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 3px 10px;
}

#hamburger-icon div {
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 5px 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.open .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-6px, 5px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-6px, 5px);
}

.open .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.open .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-6px, -6px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-6px, -6px);
}

.open .mobile-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  position: absolute;
}

.mobile-menu {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 24px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  overflow: hidden;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  background: #007991;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #78ffd6, #007991);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #78ffd6, #007991);
  /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 100;
}

.mobile-menu li {
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: 400 !important;
}

.mobile-menu li a {
  color: #fff;
}

.mobile-menu li:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

@media(max-width: 768px) {
  header {
    height: 40px;
  }
  .logo {
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    margin: 8px 10px;
  }
  header nav,
  header .access {
    display: none;
  }
  #hamburger-icon {
    display: block;
    padding: 2px 7px;
    margin-right: 5px;
  }
  #hamburger-icon div {
    width: 20px;
    height: 3px;
  }
  .mobile-menu li {
    margin-right: 15px;
  }
}

media(min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1020px) {
  .logo {
    margin: 10px;
  }
  nav ul li {
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  nav ul li a {
    padding: 5px;
  }
}

@media(min-width: 250px) and (max-width: 281px) {
  .logo {
    margin-left: -10px;
  }
  #hamburger-icon {
    margin-right: -10px;
  }
}

@media(min-width: 282px) and (max-width: 320px) {
  .logo {
    margin-left: -10px;
  }
  #hamburger-icon {
    margin-right: -10px;
  }
}


/*Card*/

.card {
  min-width: 15rem;
  flex: 1;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #fff;
  font-weight: 300 !important;
  position: relative;
}

.card .category {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: 0;
  background: #FF7F50;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 300 !important;
  padding: 5px 9px;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.card .flag {
  top: 0;
  right: -15px;
  position: absolute;
}

.card .flag button {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  right: 0;
  background: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.flag #report {
  display: none;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 22px;
  margin-right: 22px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #007bff;
}

#report p {
  padding: 2px 5px;
  top: -10px;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 0.1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card img {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  pointer-events: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  width: 100%;
  float: none;
  display: block;
  z object-fit: fill;
  height: 180px;
}

.card-panel {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: -10px;
}

.card-panel .icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  /*flex-direction: row;*/
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.card-panel .icon img {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  border: 5px solid #FFF;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #007bff;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  margin: -25px 10px 0 10px;
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card-panel .icon i {
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 30px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #007bff;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  margin: -20px 5px 0 5px;
}

.card-panel .icon .tooltip,
.card-panel .icon .tooltip1 {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background: #fff;
  color: #007bff;
  font-size: 10px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}

.card-panel .icon .tooltip:before,
.card-panel .icon .tooltip1:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 7px;
  width: 7px;
  background: #fff;
  bottom: -3px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}

.card-panel .icon:hover .tooltip,
.card-panel .icon:focus .tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  top: -60px;
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.card-panel .icon:hover .tooltip1,
.card-panel .icon:focus .tooltip1 {
  top: -92px;
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.card-panel .icon:hover i,
.card-panel .icon:active i,
.card-panel .icon:hover .tooltip,
.card-panel .icon:focus .tooltip,
.card-panel .icon .tooltip1:before {
  text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.card-panel .tooltip1 i {
  font-size: 8px;
  line-height: 13px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #007bff;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  margin: -20px 5px 0 5px;
}

.card .text {
  padding: 10px 10px;
}

.card .text h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word;
  font-weight: 500 !important;
}

.card button {
  background-color: #007bff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}

.card button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.card .see-more {
  top: 40%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.card .see-more i {
  font-size: 60px;
  color: #007bff;
}

.container-a,
.container-b {
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas: "blog-container blog-container blog-container blog-container blog-sidebar";
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.wrapper .blog-container {
  grid-area: blog-container;
}

.wrapper .blog-sidebar {
  grid-area: blog-sidebar;
}

.wrapper .blog-container span,
.wrapper .blog-sidebar span {
  background-color: #007bff;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: -1;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif !important;
}

.blog-container hr,
.blog-sidebar hr {
  width: 100%;
  color: #007bff;
  margin-top: 3.5px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -2;
}

.blog-container .blog-cards {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(270px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.widgets {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(270px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.widgets img {
  width: 100%;
  float: none;
  display: block;
  object-fit: fill;
}

.container-a .widgets,
.container-b .widgets {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.load-more {
  text-align: center;
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.load-more button {
  padding: 9px 150px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 136, 169, 1);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.load-more button:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 136, 169, 0.8);
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}


/*--MEDIA QUERIES--*/

@media(max-width: 768px) {
  .carousel {
    width: calc(100% - 60px);
    margin: 10px auto;
  }
  .carousel span,
  .wrapper .blog-container span,
  .wrapper .blog-sidebar span {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  .carousel hr {
    margin-top: 3px;
  }
  .horizontal-scroll .btn-scroll {
    padding: 0 5px;
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  .horizontal-scroll #btn-scroll-left {
    top: calc(430px/2);
  }
  .horizontal-scroll #btn-scroll-right {
    top: calc(430px/2);
  }
  .container-a,
  .container-b {
    width: 99%;
    padding: 5px;
  }
  .wrapper {
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "blog-container" "blog-sidebar";
  }
  .card {
    min-width: 100%;
  }
  .card .category {
    font-size: 8px;
    padding: 4px 7px;
    top: -8px;
  }
  .card img {
    height: 150px;
  }
  .card .flag {
    right: -7px;
    0
  }
  .card .flag button {
    font-size: 15px;
    top: -5px;
  }
  .flag #report {
    margin-top: 17px;
    margin-right: 12px;
  }
  #report p {
    padding: 1px 4px;
    font-size: 9px;
  }
  .card-panel .icon i {
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 22px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    margin: -12px 4px 0 4px;
    border: 4px solid #FFF;
  }
  .card-panel .icon img {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 4px solid #FFF;
    margin: -20px 10px 0 10px;
  }
  .card-panel .icon .tooltip,
  .card-panel .icon .tooltip1 {
    padding: 8px 8px;
    font-size: 8px;
  }
  .card-panel .icon .tooltip:before,
  .card-panel .icon .tooltip1:before {
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    bottom: -2px;
  }
  .card-panel .icon:hover .tooltip {
    top: -45px;
  }
  .card-panel .icon:hover .tooltip1 {
    top: -75px;
  }
  .card-panel .tooltip1 i {
    font-size: 8px;
    line-height: 14px;
    height: 18px;
    width: 18px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
  }
  .card .text h3 {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  .card button {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  .widgets {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(244px, 1fr));
  }
  .card .see-more {
    top: 40%;
  }
  .card .see-more i {
    font-size: 50px;
  }
  .load-more button {
    padding: 5px 30px;
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 281px) {
  .wrapper .blog-container {
    padding-right: 0;
  }
  .blog-container .blog-cards {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100%, 1fr));
  }
  .widgets {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100%, 1fr));
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="body-content">
  <header>
    <img src="img/Logo.jpg" class="logo" alt="Logo">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="index"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-pen-nib"></i> Blogs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="far fa-images"></i> product</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <ul class="access">
      <li><a href="#"><button class="accessBtn"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i> Access <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></button></a>
        <ul class="access-menu">
          <li id="signup"><a href="signup">Signup</a></li>
          <li id="signin"><a href="signin">Signin</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="hamburger-icon" onclick="toggleMobileMenu(this)">
      <div class="bar1"></div>
      <div class="bar2"></div>
      <div class="bar3"></div>
      <ul class="mobile-menu">
        <li class="active"><a href="index"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-pen-nib"></i> contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="far fa-images"></i> Product</a></li>
        <li><a href="signup">Signup</a></li>
        <li><a href="signin">Signin</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>
  <section class="container-a" aria-label="blog-content">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="blog-container">
        <span>Blogs</span>
        <hr>
        <div class="blog-cards">

          <div class="card">
            <img src="images/1.jpg">
            <p class="category">Fashion</p>
            <div class="flag">
              <button onclick=myFunction()>&#8942</button>
              <div id="report">
                <p>Report</p>
                <p>Not-interested</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--flag-->
            <div class="card-panel">
              <div class="icon">
                <div class="tooltip">14.1k</div>
                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="icon">
                <div class="tooltip">14.1k</div>
                <i class="fas fa-comment"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="icon">
                <div class="tooltip1"><i class="fas fa-crown"></i>Umananda goswami
                </div>
                <img src="images/4.jpeg">
              </div>
              <div class="icon">
                <div class="tooltip">14.1k</div>
                <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="icon">
                <div class="tooltip">14.1k</div>
                <i class="fas fa-share"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--card-panel-->
            <div class="text">
              <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</h3>
              <button>Read it</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--card-->

          <div class="card">
            <img src="images/1.jpg">
            <p class="category">Fashion</p>
            <div class="flag">
              <button onclick=myFunction()>&#8942</button>
              <div id="report">
                <p>Report</p>
                <p>Not-interested</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--flag-->
            <div class="card-panel">
              <div class="icon">
                <div class="tooltip">14.1k</div>
                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="icon">
                <div class="tooltip">14.1k</div>
                <i class="fas fa-comment"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="icon">
                <div class="tooltip1"><i class="fas fa-crown"></i>Umananda goswami
                </div>
                <img src="images/4.jpeg">
              </div>
              <div class="icon">
                <div class="tooltip">14.1k</div>
                <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="icon">
                <div class="tooltip">14.1k</div>
                <i class="fas fa-share"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--card-panel-->
            <div class="text">
              <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</h3>
              <button>Read it</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--card-->
          <div class="card">
            <img src="images/1.jpg">
            <p class="category">Fashion</p>
            <div class="flag">
              <button onclick=myFunction()>&#8942</button>
              <div id="report">
                <p>Report</p>
                <p>Not-interested</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--flag-->
            <div class="card-panel">
              <div class="icon">
                <div class="tooltip">14.1k</div>
                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="icon">
                <div class="tooltip">14.1k</div>
                <i class="fas fa-comment"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="icon">
                <div class="tooltip1"><i class="fas fa-crown"></i>Umananda goswami
                </div>
                <img src="images/4.jpeg">
              </div>
              <div class="icon">
                <div class="tooltip">14.1k</div>
                <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="icon">
                <div class="tooltip">14.1k</div>
                <i class="fas fa-share"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--card-panel-->
            <div class="text">
              <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</h3>
              <button>Read it</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--card-->
          <div class="card">
            <img src="images/1.jpg">
            <p class="category">Fashion</p>
            <div class="flag">
              <button onclick=myFunction()>&#8942</button>
              <div id="report">
                <p>Report</p>
                <p>Not-interested</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--flag-->
            <div class="card-panel">
              <div class="icon">
                <div class="tooltip">14.1k</div>
                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="icon">
                <div class="tooltip">14.1k</div>
                <i class="fas fa-comment"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="icon">
                <div class="tooltip1"><i class="fas fa-crown"></i>Umananda goswami
                </div>
                <img src="images/4.jpeg">
              </div>
              <div class="icon">
                <div class="tooltip">14.1k</div>
                <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="icon">
                <div class="tooltip">14.1k</div>
                <i class="fas fa-share"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--card-panel-->
            <div class="text">
              <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</h3>
              <button>Read it</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--card-->
          <div class="card">Card5</div>
          <div class="load-more">
            <button>Load More</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--cards-->
      </div>
      <div class="blog-sidebar">
        <span>Sidebar</span>
        <hr>
        <div class="widgets">
          <img src="images/5.jpg">
          <img src="images/4.jpeg">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

So the problem was fixed by changing `min-width` to `100%` insted of a absolute value in line 601 at your css file.

Comment: i tried it but still arising the problem

Comment: edited it for you :)

Comment: you changed only card-width to 100% right?

Comment: yes, you only need to change the "min-width" to 100% instead 14.8rem. its on line 601 in your css file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75343686/making-layout-width-100-or-adjusting-child-div-to-screen-width-of-100/75351170#75351170 
see this question, and answer Height of wrapper profile intro or profile card should be auto adjusting as per content from the work link

Comment: please refresh the codepen (isnt working anymore) and specify your problem in more details so i can help you properly :)

Comment: https://codepen.io/TA0011/pen/RwBoPbd see this link

Comment: please edit your question.. i dont realy understand what exactly you need

Comment: you just changed the pen url. please describe your problem in more detail or add images

Comment: added check....